# How to only return actual tokens, rather than empty variables when tokenizing?

Tags: python, apply, tokenize, gensim

I have a function:

```
def remove_stopwords(text):
     return [[word for word in simple_preprocess(str(doc), min_len = 2) if word not in stop_words] for doc in texts]
```

My input is a list with a tokenized sentence:

```
input = ['This', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'my', 'input']
```

Assume that `stop_words` contains the words: 'this', 'is', 'an', 'of' and 'my', then the output I would like to get is:

```
desired_output = ['example', 'input']
```

However, the actual output that I'm getting now is:

```
actual_output = [[], [], [], ['example'], [], [], ['input']]
```

How can I adjust my code, to get this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code for removing stopwords, if there is no specific reason to use your code.

```
wordsFiltered = []
def remove_stopwords(text):
    for w in text:
        if w not in stop_words:
            wordsFiltered.append(w)
    return wordsFiltered

input = ['This', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'my', 'input']

stop_words = ['This', 'is', 'an', 'of', 'my']

print remove_stopwords(input)
```

Output:

```
['example', 'input']
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions to your problem:

### Solution 1:

Your `remove_stopwords` requires an array of documents to work properly, so you modify your input like this

```
input = [['This', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'my', 'input']]
```

### Solution 2:

You change your `remove_stopwords` function to work on a single document

```
def remove_stopwords(text):
     return [word for word in simple_preprocess(str(text), min_len = 2) if word not in stop_words]
```